# How to setup “my” AC on Alexa?

Tags: smart-home, alexa, amazon-echo, ac-power

So I setup Alexa with multiple smart home ACs, one in my room and another in the guest room. I’ve given the name as Guest Room AC for that, and mine is Mohsin’s AC. But when I come home and say “Alexa, turn on my AC”, it turns on the guest room AC. How do I tell Alexa which is my AC so I can reassign it? Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: what happens of you say `Alexa, turn on Mohsin’s AC` ?

Comment: That works 70% of the time. But due to the pronunciation it ends up making mistakes sometimes and says something like “I couldn’t find a device named mohsin’s a c”.

Comment: rename `Mohsin's ac` to `my ac`

Comment: Yeah, I figured that’s an option. Sadly it’s a hack than an actual fix. Thanks for telling thou

Comment: it is unclear how Alexa determines which of the two is `my AC` ... what happens if you delete the guest room AC?